# C# WinForms OR WPF File Dialog Prompt to Open or Save or Cancel for a file that I am creating in the code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, file, dialog

I am creating a file from the user's data, on a specific users action.

Now I want to give him a custom dialog to either be able to Open or Save the File, kind of like what you get when you actually download a file.

A sample of what I want :

[image]

I am aware of the Open File Dialog (which can open an existing file from Disk) and the Save File Dialog, which allows me to save the file, but is there any Dialog or control that could have both the options for WPF or Winforms?
WPF would be preferred, but I could make do with a Winforms control too.

**EDIT :** Thanks for the feedback. Since there doesn't seem to be an inbuilt or 3rd party control ,I'm going with a custom control.

Any ideas how I can get the file type thumbnail & the File type long Name ?

The Button functionalities itself is easy enough and I can manage that.

Comment: Like you need to invent a wheel. At first glance  it should be easy to implement a user control with three buttons. What is the problem you have encountered?

Comment: I just wanted to know if there's an existing control that I might not be aware of ? Or possibly a third party or existing custom implementation ...

Comment: AFAIK, there is one for Web, but I'm unable to use that one.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going with the custom approach now.

Comment: Any ideas how I can get the file type thumbnail & the File type Name ? The Button functionalities itself is easy enough and I can manage that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For file types which are not set to open in browser, you can rely on an invisible `WebBroser` control and call `Navigate` method and pass the temp file name to it:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(@"C:\windows\temp\somefile.xyz");
```

If it's not satisfying, you need to roll your own dialog.

---

**Create Custom Download Dialog**

In case that you decide to implement a custom dialog, you can use [`SHGetFileInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762179.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to extract information about file, including Icon and File Type Description.

For example, first declare the [`SHGetFileInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762179.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [`SHFILEINFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759792.aspx) structure and required constants:

```
[DllImport("shell32")]
private static extern IntPtr SHGetFileInfo(string pszPath, uint dwFileAttributes,
    out SHFILEINFO psfi, uint cbFileInfo, uint uflags);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct SHFILEINFO {
    public IntPtr hIcon;
    public int iIcon;
    public uint dwAttributes;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
    public string szDisplayName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 80)]
    public string szTypeName;
}

private const uint FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL = 0x00000080;
private const uint SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES = 0x000000010; 
private const uint SHGFI_ICON = 0x000000100;  
private const uint SHGFI_DISPLAYNAME = 0x000000200; 
private const uint SHGFI_TYPENAME = 0x000000400;    
private const uint SHGFI_ATTRIBUTES = 0x000000800;
```

Then you can use the method this way:

```
var info = new SHFILEINFO();
SHGetFileInfo(filename, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, out info, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(info),
    SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_DISPLAYNAME | SHGFI_TYPENAME | SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES);

var fileDisplayName = info.szDisplayName;
var fileTypeName = info.szTypeName;
var fileTypeImage = Icon.FromHandle(info.hIcon).ToBitmap();
```

Then you can have such dialog:

[image]

**Download Example**

You can download a working example from the following repository:

- [r-aghaei/DownloadFileDialogExample](https://github.com/r-aghaei/DownloadFileDialogExample)
- [Zip File](https://github.com/r-aghaei/DownloadFileDialogExample/archive/master.zip)

Comment: Thanks,yes, this is the first one I tried, but i does not support all file types, and then asks me to save/download.

Plus, it loses out on the formatting and cant display the content correctly some times.

Comment: Which is why, I thought of always opening the file in its default handler. Which I can do simply enough :  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filepath);

Comment: So you need to create your own custom dialog containing a few buttons to open or save or cancel the dialog.

Comment: I just wanted a Winforms/WPF equivalent of the FileDownload control available for Web.

Comment: Yep, Im going with the custom approach now.

Comment: I shared the solution for custom dialog approach.

Comment: Thanks, marking as accepted since I got it done with my Custom approach. I just needed the right push.

Comment: #Reza Thanks for the sample, I'll make sure to give it a look to see if I can improve my own.